# Is it possible to use different .env for different services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a situation where it would be nice to have multiple .env files, one for each service in my docker-compose.yml.  Is there any way to specify a different filename to use?  Can this be done on the level of individual services?

I attempted to use the `env_file` tag, unfortunately, this sets variables for use in Dockerfile and at run-time.  The .env file, on the other hand, sets variables to be expanded in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to specify an alternative name for the `.env` file. I've wanted to be able to swap that out too, but you can see [in the source code](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/901ee4e77b3169aa81331a6dc4aa110c36422731/compose/config/environment.py#L55) that's it's coded directly to `.env`.

Is there a reason you want to split out substitution variables per service? It feels like you should be able to put the variables for all of your services into a single `.env` file.

Comment: I think this is just personal preference, but it would be nice to have an option for this so that I can switch variables expanded in docker-compose for a single service by changing a single filename in docker-compose.  Additionally, I dislike having the configuration hidden in a dot-file, though I can just use a symlink to solve that.  That said, I'm just building a single file for all of my services as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the `env_file` service option.

> You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option, just like with docker run --env-file=FILE ...:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

Source docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

Comment: That's what I thought, unfortunately, this sets environment variables used in Dockerfile and at run-time.  The .env file sets variables that can be expanded in the docker-compose rather than in the Dockerfile.  I edited my question to reflect this.