# Docker-compose specify tags from env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml like below:

```
version: '2'
services:

    micro-service:
        image: some/micro-service:${SERVICE_VERSION}
        env_file:
            - ../all-variables/${PROFILE}/micro_service.env
        ports:
            - "8085:8085"
```

And I have two files : `dev.env` and `stage.env` where `SERVICE_VERSION` and `PROFILE` are described.

Is there any way to specify concrete file when running `docker-compose up`
By default docker-compose takes `.env` file from current dir.

Is there a way to override it or another workaround ?

Comment: Somewhat related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864402/is-it-possible-to-use-different-env-for-different-services/51864489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer in the comments there is no way to do that as it is directly coded into the source [code](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/901ee4e77b3169aa81331a6dc4aa110c36422731/compose/config/environment.py#L55) to use `.env`.

However, there a couple ways to get similar behaviour.

The first way works natively with `docker-compose`, which would be to use docker-compose [override](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case) files.

So in your case you could have your base `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  micro-service:
    image: some/micro-service:1.0.0
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
```

Then you can define a `docker-compose-dev.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  micro-service:
    image: some/micro-service:dev
    env_file:
      - ../all-variables/dev/micro_service.env
```

Then you can run the following command

`$ docker-compose up -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-dev.yml up`

If you do this the values in `docker-compose-dev.yml` will override those in `docker-compose.yml`. So instead of using image `some/micro-service:1.0.0` it will use the image defined in `docker-compose-dev.yml`.

The second way would be to use [docker-app](https://github.com/docker/app). Which is a new experimental utility from the Docker team.

Basically you will create a `dockerapp` file that would look like this:

```
version: 0.0.1
name: app

---
version: '2'
services: 
  micro-service:
    image: some/micro-service:${SERVICE_VERSION}
      env_file:
        - ../all-variables/${PROFILE}/micro_service.env
      ports:
        - "8085:8085"
---
SERVICE_VERSION: latest
PROFILE: default
```

Then if you convert your `.env` files to `.yml` render the compose file with the correct variables using `docker-app`.

`docker-app render -f dev.yml | docker-compose -f - up`

Hopefully this is helpful, I am going through a similar issue when working with multiple environments with docker-compose.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for ! Thanks!